# Match str value from list of dict in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have an application that I am trying to automate. In order to collect all of the information needed, I have to run an API call against every node in the application. I do so with the following function:

```
def node_df(self, nodes):
    lst_dict = []
    for node in nodes:
        jsonstr = self.session.get_hdw_node(node)
        lst_dict.append(jsonstr)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = df1.append(lst_dict)
    drop = df2.drop(["nodeType", "timestamp"], axis=1)
    return drop
```

**Single Node JSON Output:**

```
{
    "Nodes": [{
        "id": "P1_H17_F03_JN0@00-9C7719-839318-409186-3459CB[0-1-94]",
        "timestamp": "2019-12-11T16:22:55Z",
        "name": "P1_H17_F03_JN0",
        "node": "node1@00-E4DEA9-90EB54-48BE9D-7C7D62[1-1-10]",
        "dataSet": [{
            "dev": "0x003C"
        }, {
            "dev": "0x00C2"
        }, {
            "dev": "0x002A"
        }, {
            "dev": "0x0048"
        }, {
            "dev": "0x0011"
        }, {
            "dev": "0x0024"
        }],
        "nodeType": "HardwareNodeBlock"
    }]
}
```

The output creates following DataFrame:

```
    dataSet                                             node                                            id
0   [{'dev': '0x003C'}, {'dev': '0x00C2'}, {'dev'...    node1@00-E4DEA9-90EB45-48BE9D-7C7D62[1-1-10]    P1_H17_F03_JN0@00-9C7719-839318-409...
1   [{'dev': '0x0020'}, {'dev': '0x0038'}, {'dev'...    node2@00-32BF13-BABA54-4B7FBF-B34F5B[1-1-8] P1_H14_F04_JN1@00-77E5FA-C1055C-4E0...
2   [{'dev': '0x0112'}, {'dev': '0x0113'}, {'dev'...    node2@00-32BF13-BABA54-4B7FBF-B34F5B[1-1-8] P1_H14_F04_JN2@00-F3D05C-08DB23-443...
3   [{'dev': '0x00E9'}, {'dev': '0x00EC'}, {'dev'...    node2@00-32BF13-BABA54-4B7FBF-B34F5B[1-1-8] P1_H14_F04_JN3@00-DC0EED-31DE6C-4B3...
4   [{'dev': '0x004B'}, {'dev': '0x0061'}, {'dev'...    node2@00-32BF13-BABA54-4B7FBF-B34F5B[1-1-8] P1_H14_F04_JN4@00-3A57F1-E7A3B6-44E...
```

I'm trying to match the value `'0x0113'` from `df["dataSet"]` so I can return the row to get `df["id"]`. `'0x0113'` is one of the devices attached to the Node.

Normally I would do a `df.loc[df['dataSet'].str.match('0x0113')]`, but of course it's not that simple here. How can this be done? I was thinking it would be best to consolidate the `dataSet` keys first since they all have the same key name.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That’s a slightly odd DataFrame structure, can you explain the data, format, use etc. a little bit? In the case of “0x0113”, for example, what is the desired output?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile You're right, it is an odd DataFrame. I'll update my question with more detail of how the DataFrame was constructed.

Comment: Awesome! Is that dummy data? Seeing all those single element dictionaries makes me think tuples, or even better, a single list of elements.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile it's not completely dummy data. It is just poorly designed by the creators of the application.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data at different steps in the program? What do the nodes look like? What does `jsonstr` look like?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile An example of a single node JSON output has been added to the original question.

Comment: Are the number of dev items the same across as objects/rows? Are they the only kind of value?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the devs range from at least two to ten per node. The dev ID is unique.

Comment: Alright, but there will only ever be dev items in there? Can we just use a list instead?

Comment: The dataSet list will only ever contain dev items?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile correct. Only dev items

Comment: ezpz. I’ll be back at my computer in 5 minutes, I’ll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a way around this issue. I first consolidated the keys into a single dictionary applying the following function to my DataFrame in the `node_df` function:

```
def consolidate_dataset(data):
    final = {}
    for dev in data:
        for key, val in dev.items():
            final.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
    return final


def node_df(self, nodes):
    ...
    df2 = df1.append(lst_dict)
    df2["dataSet"] = df2["dataSet"].apply(self.consolidate_dataset)
    ...
```

**Output:**

```
{'dev': ['0x003C', '0x00C2', '0x002A', '0x0048', '0x0011', '0x0024']}
```

Then I decided I don't need the key at all and replaced `consolidate_dataset` with a function to turn the `dataSet` into a list.

```
def dataset_list(data):
    final = []
    for dev in data:
        for _key, val in dev.items():
            final.append(val)
    return final
```

**Output:**

```
['0x003C', '0x00C2', '0x002A', '0x0048', '0x0011', '0x0024']
```

Now I can easily match the value `'0x0113'` in my DataFrame to get `df["id"]`:

```
df2[['0x0113' in dev for dev in df2['dataSet']]]
```

**Output:**

```
    dataSet                         node                                     id
2   ['0x0112', '0x0113', '0x0114']  node2@00-32BF13-BABA45-4B7FBF-B34F5B[1-1-8] P1_H14_F04_JN31@00-F3D05C-08DB23-443...
```

Comment: I would suggest using a defaultdict in `consolidate_dataset`, and using `.map()` over `.apply()`. Also, have you considered using a class for this, instead of a DataFrame? I'm glad you figured something out :)